# MS Access 2010 Rollup data

Tags: ms-access-2010

Looking for a solution to the below:

Raw table:

```
     ID:      Cat:
      1         Yes
      1         No
      2         Yes
      2         No
      3         No
```

Outcome:

```
  ID:     Cat:
   1       Yes-No
   2       Yes-No
   3       No
```

Anythoughts: I used Update queriers 
 Steps taken: Created another table

"Unique Table"

```
 ID     Yes     No     "Both (Concatenate Yes and No Columns)"
```

Join from this table...
I'm sure this is a more efficient way to do this without using VBA. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately JET SQL does not provide an easy way to do this. You need to use a VBA. You can the function already provided by Allen Browne [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)(). This function will return the corresponding concatenated values.

Just copy the code from the Allen Brown's site into a Standard Module, save it with a name called **mod_Concat**. Do a compile of the code, so your compiler understands the function.

Then create a SQL Query something like.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    ConcatRelated("Cat", "rawTable", "ID = " & [ID]) As NewConcat
FROM 
    rawTable;
```

Comment: @MrJohn, why would that be?

Comment: Probably multiple reasons but I would say it's most likely user error. I'm getting an error 3464: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Is ID actually text type? in that case make sure that the ConcatRelated is something like, `ConcatRelated("Cat", "rawTable", "ID = '" & [ID] & "'") As NewConcat`

Comment: Thank you this worked and I see from the explaination from Allen Browne to add quotes in the third arugement for text fields. This function will be beneifical and I appreciate the help.

Comment: @MrJohn, glad you got it sorted ! Thank you for marking it as answer. Good luck !